# Permission Error When Exporting to $JAVA_HOME on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, macos, zsh

Whenever I try to set my Java Home `export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home)` in my .zshenv or .zshrc files, I get an `/Users/{USER NAME HERE}/.zshenv:1: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home` error when starting up my terminal. In fact, I can't seem to be able to export anything (for example, `export TEST=$(/Users/{USER NAME HERE})` gives me a `zsh: permission denied: /Users/{USER NAME HERE}` error. I already gave full disk access in system preferences, but that doesn't seem to be working either. I am the only user on my computer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `$(foo)` bit means, loosely, "run `foo` as a program, then insert its output here and go on as if I had typed it", which is not what you want here. Just do

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/...
```

The `$()` bit is useful when you use the Mac's Java selection mechanism, and run e.g.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v16)
```

In that case, you're running a program, and setting `JAVA_HOME` to the output of that program.

Comment: even without $() I am still getting the permission denied error...

Comment: @MathewRuberg If you get a permission error on a simple `export` operation, you are doing *something* wrong, but it is hard to tell what. I suggest asking a new question, showing exactly what you did and what error message you got. However, there’s a risk it will be closed as off topic for Stack Overflow and more fit for one of the other sites.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same issue today, and figured out out to fix it.
Remember to close/open your shell (or resource it) after making the change in your profile script.

In Z shell, the export statement is a bit different than bash, as you can set the environment variable without the $().

Instead of:
*export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home)*

Use the simpler zsh form with quote marks for the path:
*export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home"*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Notice that this is not a zsh-vs-bash difference, it’s a doing-completely-different-things difference. `$()` does the same thing in both shells.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my fix in case it helps some else (or me the next time I run into this issue). This was done on a 2021 M1 Macbook Pro (Ventura 13.3.1 a) - if you're reading this in 2-3 years I hope this saves you some time.

I was running into this permission issue trying to get Expo's native module tutorial working (https://docs.expo.dev/modules/native-module-tutorial/) - iOS had its own issues with ruby/gem version chaos and with Android I had trouble with the above and when setting $JAVA_HOME I was running into the issue above - I wanted to configure the global version of JAVA so that Expo could build properly.

I managed to get past the error with JENV (https://www.jenv.be/) and using Android Studio to get a few versions of the JDK to play with (`Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`) - you can easily download new Gradle JDKs here.

Openjdk Version 20 which is what I had installed previously (via brew) seemed to have compiler issues with expo's code so I installed Corretto v17 (via Android Studio). In Android Studio I could see the Home directory of this JDK so I was able to add it to the available versions to JENV (`jenv add ~~~jdk home directory here~~~`) and then set that as the global version `jenv global 17` - from there the $JAVA_HOME issues seemed to be resolved as the compiler was able to find and use the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this problem by changing:

> export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home)
> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

to:

> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home

- deleting the `$()` that encloses the values of the variables

PD: You can get this file by writing in the console(iTerm at Mackbook Pro m3 in my case):

> nano ~/.zshrc

After deleting the `$()` safe the file and run in the terminal:

> source ~/.zshrc